# How to make json array validation in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have one json array like and it's have limited questions.

```
{
"section_slug": "personal_info",
"questions": [
    {
    "question_slug":"whats-your-hobbies",
    "answers":[
            {
                "answer_slug":"Cooking",
                "answer":"Cooking"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "question_slug": "education",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer_slug": "Masters",
                "answer": "Masters"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question_slug": "state",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer_slug": "Alaska",
                "answer": "Alaska"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

}

I want to need expected outpoot is :

1. "section_slug is required",
2. "education is required",
3. "education answer is required",
4. "State is required",
5. "State answer is required"

In case user have not added quastion like 'city'
So need show error city is required.

Please I need your supports.
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest decoding the json into an array and then pass it through [Laravel's Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: That JSON is invalid, having two trailing commas. It is not clear when your required output should be there. Inside answers? When is what slug required?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this in the case of receiving a request from a form, then in this case you'd better use the request class:

```
php artisan make:request StoreFormRequest
// app/Http/Requests/StoreFormRequest
```

And denote the rules of all fields inside it:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'section_slug' => 'required|regex:/^[a-z-0-9]+$/'
        // ...

    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'section_slug.required' => 'Slug is required.',
        'section_slug.regex' => 'Slug has incorrectly format.'
    ];
}
```

The controller method code will not be executed if the validation of the fields is not passed. Use like this:

```
public function store(StoreFormRequest $request)
{
    Form::create($request->validated());
}
```